# Autofill formulas with a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, autofill

I have combination of data on column G that I am separating out. The formulas for mid/find are working correctly, but when I try to add the autofill code that I found online at the bottom, it errors out.

```
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-1],FIND(""ASL"",RC[-1])+4,3)"

Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-2],FIND(""DEPT"",RC[-2])+5,2)"

Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-3],FIND(""ST"",RC[-3])+3,2)"

Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-4],FIND(""REIN"",RC[-4])+5,5)"

Range("H2:K2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the formulas to each column by putting the formulas into an array and writing each formula to a column range. You don't need to use `AutoFill`. This code will insert the formulas into columns H - K from row 2 to last row(value) in column A. Please change the worksheet as needed. Comments are provide in the code.

```
Sub InsertFormulasInColumnsWithArray()

'Set your worksheet variable, change the worksheet as needed
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Put all your formulas into an array. the `_` connects each section into one line of code, easier to read.

Dim formulaArr As Variant: formulaArr = Array("=MID(RC[-1],FIND(""ASL"",RC[-1])+4,3)", _
"=MID(RC[-2],FIND(""DEPT"",RC[-2])+5,2)", "=MID(RC[-4],FIND(""REIN"",RC[-4])+5,5)", _
"=MID(RC[-4],FIND(""REIN"",RC[-4])+5,5)")


x = 8 'assign the variable `x` to the first column `H = 8`

    With ws 'use the With statement to ensure you are adding the formulas to the correct worksheet
    
        For i = LBound(formulaArr) To UBound(formulaArr) 'loop through the 4 formulas in your array
        
            'Starting at `row 2`, `column 8` (x = 8)`,
            'resize the the range to the value of the last row in `Column A`
            'you subtract `-1` because you start the range on `Row 2`
            'Write the first formula to the range in `Column H`,
            'in the second loop you will write the second formula in Column I, etc.

            .Cells(2, x).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1).FormulaR1C1 = formulaArr(i)
            
            x = x + 1 'increase x by 1 to select the next column
            
        Next i 'Loop to the next formula in the array, until the last formula is done
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this worked and this is definitely a lot faster than when I was looping through pasting the formula one by one. However, when I open a second file and apply the code again, it does not seem to work. It works again if I close the macro and re-write it. Do I need to reset something?

Comment: I changed the Thisworkbook to ActiveWorkbook and it is working.

Comment: Glad I could help